# Request timeout in Odoo

Tags: api, timeout, odoo, xml-rpc

I am using Odoo External API and move data from the database to the Odoo Contacts.

Authenticating and reading from API is being succeeded however I am not able to send a POST request, as I am getting the following error.

`[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

As Server is up, what are the reasons for it and how can I solve it?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Did you advance with this in any way?

Comment: @WilboBaggins as far as I remember, no. It was a server issue in our case.

Comment: Thanks for the update! In my case it turned out an IPv6 configuration issue; our test system was talking to Odoo over IPv4, our production system over IPv6, but Odoo wasn't configured to respond over IPv6 so the requests timed out.